# Sending the whole object just to update status?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, oop

Aspx page.

many fields in the form

we are representing all the fields in a JS object.

we are **only** changing the status of the record in the UI to "0". ( in the ui)

we need to save the new status in DB.

---

question :

should we

**1)** populate all the fields to the objects , send the whole object to server  via ajax and walkthrough his fields in the server to see which has changed ?

**or**

**2)** generate a special command for changing status **only**  , and send the command with ajax to the server ?

the first one is more OOP'ed but I dont find any logic at sending all the fields to the server  - just to change the status...

p.s.

this is coming from an argue between me and a colleague

I suggested the second one. he  , the first one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think of it from a CQS/CQRS perspective (command query separation / command query responsibility segregation), you'd go for the second approach (your approach) because what you're describing is a specific command that you're issuing and handling in your code.  Your command that you're sending up contains all the information needed to tell your system to do something (imperative tone).  This way, you have code performing single responsibilities, which leads to more readable and more maintainable code.

I'd side with you in your argument.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason to send an entire object just to pass one value.  If this were all occurring within a piece of backend code, the object already existed and you were only passing a reference, that's one thing.  Since you are passing this over the network, the smaller the data sent the better.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Generic Handler (.ashx) and call it via Ajax when the user decided to make a status change.  You would only have to pass in the id of the object and the new status.

OOP is good at a lot of things, but making quick/light edits isn't really one of them.

The only thing to be aware of is any secondary logic that would normally kick off due to a property change.  For example, does changing the status involve having to revalidate the entire object?

If not, don't worry about it.  If so, consider how you might simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose the alternative that is less work. From an architectural standpoint this does not matter much.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested elsewhere, you can use a Generic Handler (.ashx), Web Service (.asmx) or even a WebMethod tagged public method on the page in question.  In this case, what you want is a simple Ajax call (not to be confused with Microsoft Ajax Toolkit).

See [jQuery's post method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for example.  It's pretty straightforward to make a call like this.  For a classic webforms project, I would personally go with an ashx, or asmx over the WebMethod tagging inside of your aspx.  For MVC there are more options (JsonResult).

One of the serious issues I have with ASP.Net WebForms is the viewstate and the sheer amount of data transferred on every request.  Better to have simple/lighter handlers, or web services meant to be targetted from JS.